# Create command when cloning github repository

Tags: shell, github

Today, I went and looked at the Jelly github page. I found this. [image]
I noticed that after they cloned the repo(and moving to the jellylanguage directory), they were able to use the "jelly" command. How is this possible? And how can I do it myself?

Comment: Because they installed the command by running `pip install --upgrade --user .`.

Comment: I tried it myself, the command wasn't there.

Comment: You probably don't have the correct directories in your `$PATH`. When run as a non-root user, `pip` installs scripts into `~/.local/bin`.

Comment: What does `which jelly` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an executable binary. You can compile code to create a natively executable binary that can be run as `./a` - then you can put that in `/usr/local/bin` to be able to use it from anywhere OR add the directory where that binary is to your path environment variable